# Why am I getting this "CONDITION EVALUATION DELTA" output?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I made some changes on my server but I do not know which of these changes causes this log output:

```
==========================
CONDITION EVALUATION DELTA
==========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

    None


Negative matches:
-----------------

   SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration, webSecurityConfig (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' (OnClassCondition)
         - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider,org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' authenticationManager and found beans of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' appUserDetailsService and found beans of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider' daoAuthenticationProvider (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) found beans named springSecurityFilterChain (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None
```

This is really not telling me anything.

What does it even mean? Is there something broken because the server is still working fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The condition evaluation delta is a feature of Spring Boot's DevTools. It is described in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-restart-logging-condition-delta) as follows:

> By default, each time your application restarts, a report showing the condition evaluation delta is logged. The report shows the changes to your application’s auto-configuration as you make changes such as adding or removing beans and setting configuration properties.

In the case shown in your question, some changes were made to security-related beans which affected security auto-configuration. There is nothing broken. The output is attempting to help you to understand how the changes you are making to your application are affecting its auto-configuration.

You can turn off the logging of the delta if you wish. To do so, set the following property:

```
spring.devtools.restart.log-condition-evaluation-delta=false
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the explanation. I wasn't sure because some of the output seemed like an issue for me. Especially the part "*negative matches*". Didn't know what it was about but I guess if there actually was a problem I'd notice. Never saw that output before that's also why I was a but surprised.

Answer (score 4):

This is generated when the **log level** for the application is set to **trace** or **debug**.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur even if you did not make any changes. It appears to be a bug.

My authentication is disabled in a configuration class with `permitAll()` and works as expected 100% of the time when starting the application fresh.

However, when the restarter kicks in, I will frequently see a `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` delta and, when I refresh my browser, I am presented with an erroneous login screen.

Doing another build (that actually changes something, in order to trigger the restarter) or an IntelliJ 'Update application', will usually show another delta (going from auto config, back to my config) and then the login screen is no longer presented. Usually, not always - sometimes takes 2 or I give up and stop+start.

As you can imagine, this is VERY frustrating. On the plus side, my app is very lightweight and there is very little difference between a stop+start and using the restarter. I am simply changing my habits and will be able to remove a dependency from my project!